# Error while attempting to run IBM TKE command with Hyper Protect Crypto Services

Tags: ibm-cloud

I tried to setup the Hyper Protect Crypto Services in IBM Cloud.  After I provisioned an instance, setup the IBM CLI, I attempted to run some of the TKE commands from the getting started page.  But when I run this command, it fails with:
ibmcloud tke domains
FAILED
API endpoint not recognized when determining target URLs.

Comment: What commands are you running to get that error?

Comment: ibmcloud tke domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you might not be connected to the correct API Endpoint.  You can run 'ibmcloud api' to see what your current API Endpoint is set to.  Hyper Protect Crypto is currently only available in the us-south region, so the endpoint you need would be https://api.ng.bluemix.net.

To set this region you would issue 'ibmcloud api https://api.ng.bluemix.net'  The ng part determines the region you are in, so later on if you are in dallas or australia, it would be a different endpoint name.